# Подскажите как заставить работать ng-click из под placemark.balloonContentFooter (yandex-maps-api)?

Tags: c#, angularjs, yandex-maps-api

Помогите.
Как заставить работать  ng-click из под placemark.balloonContentFooter

Есть основная форма(вкладка на страничке) со списком объектов, на каждом объекте

работает ссылка типа `<a href='#' ng-click='showCard(row)'></a>`, по нажатии которой, вызывается  функция (открывается модальное окно).

Аналогичное действие хочу сделать на другой вкладке, где расположена карта, при нажатии кнопки в балуне точки на самой карте:

```
placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([data.data[i].lon, data.data[i].lat], {
balloonContentHeader: "<strong>" + data.data[i].name + "</strong>",
balloonContentBody: popUp,
balloonContentFooter: "<a href='#' ng-click='showCard(data.data[i])'>Страница        
                   мониторинга объекта</a>",

hintContent: "<strong>" + data.data[i].name + "</strong>" + popUp
}, custompreset);
```

Но вызова функции не происходит при этом

Comment: Мне кажется, этот код не скопилируется. Вам нужна помощь с синтаксисом языка C#? Или я не понял вопроса.

Comment: Код вывода карты все работает. Не происходит вызов функции showCard() из балуна на карте, ng-click не передается в javascript. По нажатии такой же ссылки не в контейнере карты отрабатывает нормально а в другом блоке странички ng-click работает. Просто не понимаю как заставить заработать именно из балуна у точки на карте

Comment: Расставьте кавычки в коде. Пока не понятно, есть у вас там ошибки или нет.

Comment: Сам код компилируется нормально. При нажатии точки на карте выходит окно с описанием balloonContentHeader, balloonContentBody, balloonContentFooter (содержит гиперссылку при нажатии которой должно срабатывать событие ,но этого не происходит в функцию не заходит). Пробовал отлавливать событие balloonopen но это не то. Нужно именно из содержимого самого balloon действие выполнять

Comment: `showCard(data.data[i])` как вы думаете, JavaScript в курсе, что такое `data.data[i]`? У вас там есть в HTML документе такой объект `data`?

Comment: даже если сделать любую другую функцию без передаваемых аргументов она не срабатывает. Действие не передается в .controller

Comment: `ng-click='alert("Hello World!")'` тоже не срабатывает?

Comment: `ng-click='alert("Hello World!")'` нет не сработал. Ни ошибок ничего не показывает тоже. Такое ощущение что происходит в контейнере закрытом и ему недоступны какие либо действия не заложенные в ymaps.

Comment: А если не `ng-click`, а `onclick` написать?

Comment: На `onclick` так же нет реакции